# What are the types of damage can a voltage sag cause?

Tags: voltage

According to this [site](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_sag), a voltage sag happens when the rms voltage decreases between 10 and 90 percent of nominal voltage for one-half cycle to one minute.

What types of damage can a voltage sag done to any electronic devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While technically not "electronic devices", motors are generally affected the worst.

Motors whose speed is determined by the mains frequency (both asynchronous and synchronous AC motors) will not slow down significantly.
Instead, a higher current will be drawn to "compensate" for the decreased voltage, possibly in excess of the rated maximum. Brownout conditions can thus cause motor windings to drastically overheat, since resistive heating is proportional to the square of the current.

Commutated motors like universal motors and DC motors running on rectified mains will slow down proportionally to the voltage. They will generally not get damaged, unless the load somehow increases at lower speed or cooling is impaired.

Variable frequency drives will normally protect the motors and either shut down or reduce the speed in response.

It's rare for electronics to not have undervoltage protection these days, and even when they don't they are unlikely to suffer damage.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the AC environment - motors and such.

In a DC equipment environment, AC is rectified to DC, and the DC in turn is regulated to whatever the desired output voltage is (DC-DC).

This conversion stage takes an input voltage (Vin) and converts in to our desired output voltage (Vout).

If Vin changes, the converter has to compensate for this change to keep the Vout at the desired output level. This is called Line Regulation (The effect of changes in input voltage on the output voltage of the converter).

If the converter does not have very good line regulation, the output voltage of the converter will change when there is a voltage sag.

This in turn can cause large changes in current or voltage, damaging components or causing unwanted behavior.